# Error in deploying clickonce windows app with crystal reports when deploying

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports, wamp

I have and error in launching my crystal report viewer and loading the reports from my database after I deploy my windows based click once app into other computer

[image]

I think the problem is that my .rpt files path file is hard coded like this thats why it cannot find the .rpt file when deployed to other computers.

```
 Public Sub PrintReceiptSearch()
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    cryRpt.Load("C:\Users\Arcus HP Server\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ArcusTechnologiesPayParkingSystem\ArcusTechnologiesPayParkingSystem\Forms\Users\Cashier\Printing\CrystalReportPrintReceiptSearch.rpt")
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = print
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("My Parameter")
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
    crParameterValues.Clear()
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
    FormPrintReceiptSearch.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    FormPrintReceiptSearch.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Is my conclusion right? Is there any solutions to fix this? So my program will be error free when I deploy it to other computers. Thank you in advance and more power!

Answer (score 0):

1) remove  `identity impersonate="true`  tag from web.config and it working properly..

2) The system cannot find the path specified.
This simply means that the path is incorrect that you are using to refer the path.

Either, use a absolute path directly OR use a correct relative path. You would need to make sure that the path is correct such that file is found and used.

Comment: I only have app.confi and it doesnt have the identity impersonate, the path is corret it is working in my main pc but when i deploy it to other pc using clickonce method it doesnt work. Can you give me more possible solutions sir thank youuu! @Prakash